Sum rows that match a criteria
I want to sum the values of rows that have a specific value in their first column.
Sample Data



∷
A
B
C
D




1
A
10
10
10


2
B
20
20
20


3
B
30
30
30


4
A
40
40
40



For example, if the criteria I want to match is "A" then the formula would return 150 because "A" is matched in A1 and SUM(B1:D1)=30 and also matched in A4 and SUM(B1:D1)=120
I tried with SUMIF but it did not work.
I also tried the following formula but it returns the wrong number:
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5="A",SUM(B2:D4))))  


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question, replace dummy values like row 1 with realistic-looking numbers that you are trying to add, and insert a another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5="A",SUM(B2:D4))))  

gives wrong number, because you're summing all the data first inside the IF:  SUM(B2:D4). This gives SUM of all the values.
You should  only use SUM after the IF filtering:
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5="A",B2:D4)))

This also won't work, because the  vertical size of the arrays are different. A1:A5 has vertical size of 5, while B2:D4 has vertical size of 3. Fix the size, we have,
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5="A",B1:D5)))

Et Voila!

Assuming I understood correctly your question, you can simply write:




colA
colB
colC




(row 2)
A
1
1


(row 3)
B
3
3


(row 4)
B
3
3


(row 5)
A
1
1


(row 8)
B*




(row 9)
Result
12**





cellA8 has a variable input of "B"
** is where the formula returns the result value =12
and where the formula is the sum of all values in the DataRows (here rows 2,3,4 and 5) which have "B" as a criteria in ColA.

formula in B9 here
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER($B$2:$5,$A2:$A5=$A$8)),0)

Instead of using $B$2:$5, you may use named ranges; this allows for a dynamic range. the formula for this would be
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER(DataRows,sumFor=$A$8)),0)


It works if I use one condition for the filter but it returns 0 when I add the second condition
my table is located C33:F37 - column C - includes criterion and the data I want to sum is in D334:F337
this one works:
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER(D334:F337,D333:F333=G345)),0)
G344 is row criterion - month 1, month 2, month 3
if I replace the condition and filter the columns "A" etc - it also works:
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER(D334:F337,C334:C337=G344)),0)
G345 is Criterion "A"
but if I put them together, the formula that gives me "0"
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER(D334:F337,D333:F333=G345,C334:C337=G344)),0)

Taivo, apologies for not getting the table displaying properly in my reply. The filter() function refers to a tabular data range FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, …]). So it Filters the specified range eg.A334:F338 where condition1 is firstRange= "A" and condition2= "month 1"). this filter will then select data where the two conditions are met. The sum(Filter()) simply sums up all numerical values filtered but if no numerical values are found  the IFNA() returns a 0. The whole formula will only work if the data to be filtered AND both conditional values are in the filtered dataRows.

looking at your table example, the formula IFNA(SUM(FILTER(DataRange,ColArange=G345,ColBrange=G345)),0) will sum up the numerical values filtered in all rows that will meet condition1 ColA range=G345 AND condition2 ColB range=G344. If one or both conditions in the selected ranges are not met, the formula will return a zero.

Please [edit] your answer with relevant details don't put them in  comments.  Your answer would be better if you fixed the markdown and put formulas in code blocks.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You were on the right track but should use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM as it is already an array formula:
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A4="A")*B1:D4)

SUMPRODUCT
This is equivalent but shorter than:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((A1:A4="A")*B1:D4))

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((A1:A4="A")*B1:D4))

ARRAYFORMULA  SUM

Thank you so much.
I got it done with Sum + Array formula + If.

To add the numbers in rows where column A1:A equals "A", use this pattern:
=sum(filter(B1:D, A1:A = "A"))

To add the numbers where column A1:A equals "A" or "B", use this:
=sum(filter(B1:D, (A1:A = "A") + (A1:A = "B")))

If you need to match by several keys, or by a range that contains the keys, use this:
=sum(filter(B1:D, match(A1:A, G1:G7, 0)))

...where G1:G7 is the range that contains the keys you want to match.
See filter() and match().
